# Contact page on website sends visitor to second form

Tags: php, contacts

When pressing send on my contact page (www.mainmanfilms.com/contact.html) I am sent to my contact-form-handler.php page that requires the visitor to re-type their information.  Is there a way to may it one-fluid step? Ideally, they press send and receive my thank-you message. Anything you can offer is appreciated.

Comment: Please include your code, as it stands it is very difficult to answer your question without it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Here is the HTML Code:

Comment: I tried copy & pasting but received this message; too long by 665 characters

Comment: If easier, please send me an e-mail to: info@mainmanfilms.com and I can forward the entire html and php code.  Thanks, Art

Comment: @user2740766 - you can edit your question and include the code in there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can leave the `action` attribute empty and configure the form to `POST` to itself.

Normally, you'd do something like this:

```
<form action="contact-form-handler.php" method="post">
```

If you want to process the form and display the output in the same page, you need to make the following change (note the `action` attribute being empty:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

An example:

```
<?php    
    if (isset($_POST['formsubmit'])) {
        //form was submitted, do other stuff
        echo $_POST['username']; //example
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">    
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="submit" name="formsubmit" />    
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I will try that approach. When trying to copy the actual code I get this message; "too long by 665 characters"